# How to revert dropdown select option when cancel button is clicked using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Hi guys I got following code from net and modified as per my need but didn't work as expected.

```
var lastValue;

$("#changer").bind("click", function(e){
    lastValue = $(this).val();
}).bind("change", function(e){
    changeConfirmation = confirm("Really?");
    if (changeConfirmation) {
        // Proceed as planned
    } else {
        //$(this).val(lastValue);
        DummyFun();
    }
});

function DummyFun()
{
    alert(lastValue);
    $(this).val(lastValue);
}
```

Here is the code where I got from and it is working fine [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Swader/gbdMT/). How can I make mine working as in the fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `$(this)` in your DummyFun function to refer to the select element because it's out of scope.

```
function DummyFun()
{
    alert(lastValue);
    $("#changer").val(lastValue);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the function DummyFun. `this` is not referring to the element input is no longer in scope. `this` is referring to what is calling the function. use the following :

```
var lastValue;

$("#changer").bind("click", function(e){
    lastValue = $(this).val();
}).bind("change", function(e){
    changeConfirmation = confirm("Really?");
    if (changeConfirmation) {
        // Proceed as planned
    } else {
        //$(this).val(lastValue);
        DummyFun(e.currentTarget);
    }
});

function DummyFun(target)
{
    alert(lastValue);
    $(target).val(lastValue);
}
```